# Какую ORM лучше использовать: Room или ActiveAndroid для Android

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, android-room

Читая множество статей об различных ORM, сошелся на выборе между Room или ActiveAndroid. Хотел бы узнать ваше мнение, что будет лучше и в каких ситуациях нужно применять ту или инную ORM.

Comment: Realm посмотрите еще - это чистая noSQL база данных, написанная на С, гораздо быстрее ORM прослоек над SQLite. Из ваших вариантов я бы отдал предпочтение Room. Еще для простых задач стоит рассмотреть Objectbox. Оба предложенных мной решения производительнее ваших вариантов